# Form based authentication in Jboss AS

Tags: authentication, jboss

I am looking into [Enabling Form-based Authentication](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Security_Guide/Enabling_FORM_Authentication.html) tutorial and my question is:

My `web.xml`:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

**Questions:**

1. Should I create now common login page `login.html`?
2. Should it contain `POST form`? Post where to (I mean what action servlet for this form is)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it written in [tutorial](http://The%20server%20recognizes%20form%20authentication%20requests%20only%20when%20the%20URI%20ends%20with%20/j_security_check%20and%20at%20least%20the%20%20j_username%20%20and%20%20j_password%20%20parameters%20exist.) you provided:

> The server recognizes form authentication requests only when the URI
>   ends with **/j_security_check** and at least the  **j_username**  and 
>   **j_password**  parameters exist.

So `login` screen suppose to look like:

```
<h3>Login Form</h3>

<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    Email:<input type="text" name="j_username"/><br/><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="j_password"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```